# Grand total update on billing information save in onepage checkout ---Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, grand-total

I have created a custom module to update grand total but I need to update grand total only after filling address information on one page checkout because I have to check particular postal/zip code that user added and based on that have to update grand total.Here is my config file code

```
   <checkout_onepage_savePayment>
        <observers>
        <magepal_mycheckout_order_observer>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>MagePal_MyCheckout_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>sendemail</method>
        </magepal_mycheckout_order_observer>
        </observers>
    </checkout_onepage_savePayment>
```

Observer.php code

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
    $baseGrandTotal = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $partialPrice = $grandTotal + 10;
    $basePartialPrice = $baseGrandTotal + 10;
    $quote->setGrandTotal($partialPrice);
    $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($basePartialPrice);
    $quote->save();
```

I have tried several other events but when I reach to review order step,no change to grand total.

Can anybody please point me out where I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Any event of save of `checkout_onepage_savePayment` does not exit in magento.

There is an events is fire on every controller dispatch.If i guess that billing has been save it `checkout/onepage/saveBilling` then it dispatch event for this route  is

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling
```

you get data from using :

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
```

checkout object from

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard controller action events: `'controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()`

In the case of the saveBilling action the event is `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling`

and for saveShipping is 
`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShiping`.

You can access the values sent to that action by

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

**I hope this will help you.**